# How to restrict number of nodes per content type?

Tags: users

How can we restrict number of nodes allowed per content type. Let suppose if we allow 5 nodes then no one including the admin user can add the 6th node of that content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible solution to achieve the above is by checking the node count of that content type in [hook_node_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) as below:

```
/**
* Implements hook_node_validate().
*/
function MyModule_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  // For now assign the static values to CONENT_TYPE and MAX_NODES
  // however you can make it dynamic, and get those values using variable_get().
  $content_type = 'CONTENT_TYPE';
  $max_nodes = 'MAX_NODES';
  $node_count = 0;

  // Create a check for the content type.
  if ((isset($node->type)) && ($node->type === $content_type)) {
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
    $node_count = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', $content_type)
      // To get published nodes only, use: ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->count()
      ->execute();

    // Check if the node count exceeds the max_node value.
    if ($node_count > $max_nodes) {
      form_set_error('FIELD_NAME', t('Reached the maximum limit of creation of nodes for this content type.'));
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly you can do with the `Rules` also, but the above method seems better to me.

Comment: Please make it a bit more easier for me to impliment, just let me know where to insert this code ? In template.php ??

Comment: @Fahad Insert the code in custom module file(`.module`), however don't forget to replace this values(`$content_type = 'CONTENT_TYPE';
  $max_nodes = 'MAX_NODES';`) with what you want.

Comment: I have created a module using your code changed the values of $content_type and $max_nodes turn on the module but its not working. I am still able to create new nodes of the content type which I want to restrict.

Comment: I will accept it. Does this code restrict the user1 to create nodes ??

Comment: @Fahad yeah it can!!, I have checked it on my local and seems to be working fine, have you checked it the machine name of content type is correct, also check the field_name you are providing in the `form_set_error`. Also it would be good if you clear the cache

Comment: I have only changed these values
  $content_type = 'front_banner';
  $max_nodes = '1';

do I need to change some thing else ??

Comment: Few things: 1.)Check the machine name of content type is correct. 2.)`FIELD_NAME` you are providing in the `form_set_error`, for now you can set it to `title` (if you don't know the field_name of any field). 3.)As you have set the '$max_nodes' to `1` so it may be the reason that you will get error when you are going to save 2nd node(if earlier you had NO nodes of that content type). 4.)Check whether you have changed the `MODULE_NAME` in the hook.

Comment: forget to change the function name MyModule. Works great now Thank you :)

Comment: @Fahad aah ... anyways Cheers!!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried the [Node Limit](https://drupal.org/project/node_limit) module?

> The Node Limit module allows administrators to restrict the number of nodes of a specific type that roles or users may create. For example, if a site has an "Advertiser" role that can create "advertisement" nodes, then the node limit administrator can restrict all users in that role to a specific number of nodes. He may also restrict users on a per-user basis.

You could create a role just for node limit and assign ALL users (including the admin) to that role.

Comment: last time I saw that was not available for d7 still in alpha version, let me try it